# Composer requires php version 7 ->

Tags: php, laravel

I have uploaded my laravel project on a subdomain which requires php 7 and above. I have updated the subdomain to use php 7. However when run the `composer install`, it says my php version is 5.6, which is the global version. In the project, i check the version `php -v` and it shows the version as `php v7`.

How come the composer is running with php version 5.6 ? Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can skip platform check with this:

```
composer install --ignore-platform-reqs
```

otherwise you can run:

```
php composer.phar install
```

to use the php exetutable that you prefer

Answer (score 0):

As and alternative you can also use [`docker`](https://hub.docker.com/_/composer) image of `composer`:

```sh
docker run --rm --interactive --tty \
  --volume $PWD:/app \
  composer install
```

Answer (score 0):

Let Composer know the version of PHP you are using in your Laravel app by including a `platform` key in the `config` section of your `composer.json` file and reinstalling composer.

For instance, if you have the version of php7 as 7.1.3, you can update `composer.json` like this:

```
{ 
    "name": ".../...", 
    "config": { 
        "platform": { 
            "php": "7.1.3" 
        } 
    }, 
    "require": {
        ... 
    } 
}
```

**Note**: The the PHP version you provide with the `platform` key is the version of php for the environment where your app is installed, while the version you provide with the `require` key is the minimum php requirement for your application.